# How could we set CSS Margin according element depth?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have following html structure -

```
<ul>
    <li><span>1st</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>2nd</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>3th</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span>4th</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span>5th</span>
                                        <ul>
                                           ... 
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And want to output like that -

[image]

And for this i used CSS child selector with following class -

```
ul li span
{
    padding-left:0px;
}


ul li > ul li span
{
    padding-left:10px;
}

ul li > ul li > ul li span
{
    padding-left:20px;
}

ul li > ul li > ul li > ul li span
{
    padding-left:30px;
}

ul li > ul li > ul li > ul li > ul li span
{
    padding-left:40px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2P6Aq/1/)

It's working perfect, But here i want to get my desired output using any shorthand CSS trick (not as above parent-child structure i.e.  ul li > ul li > ul li > ul li....). Because on my web page i  have `N-levels` of `UL-LI` structure. And i don't want to define  `N-levels` CSS class to set margin.

Mean I don't want to define my class with `N-levels` structure like that -

```
ul li > ul li > ul li > ul li > ul li > .....  > (n-1)ul li > ul li span
    {
        padding-left:(n) * 10px; //-- Set margin according level
    }
```

So, There is any way exist in `CSS` to do this work?

and if not than can i do this using `Jquery` and how?

I don't want this - [image]

I want to every sub-node started at "0px" like that -

[image]

Thank of bunch in advance, any help would be appreciable... !!!

Comment: Take a look here, without any css, the output is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/Nqth9/

Comment: @Sari Alalem: Yes, you are right. But i don't want to give margin OR padding to my UL. Because i want to set border-bottom and border must be started at "0px" means no left margin and padding.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, the jsfiddle example doesn't give it any margin css nor padding css

Comment: @IshanJain then give a left padding to `<li>`, Since they are nested the padding grows

Comment: @SariAlalem: Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nqth9/2/. I don't want my tree look like than (Means I want span border takes no left margin OR padding)

Comment: I uderstand thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Simply put `padding-left: 10px;` on the `ul` itself

Comment: the problem with this is it reduces the ability to style it, that is why its being marked now.....

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery:

```
$('ul').each(function(index){
   $(this).find('span:first').css("padding-left",index*10+"px")
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2P6Aq/3/)**

Comment: Your code works nice. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/2P6Aq/6/. you can see in Fiddle the "6th", "7th", "8th" .. etc elements take margin in respect of (index * 10 ). But I want the "6th" element started at 0 index. Can you please help me to full-fill this requirement.

Comment: No, I don't want this. Please see my question - "Section -> every sub-node started at "0px""

Comment: No, It's also not full-fill my requirement. It's not provide me o/p like my second image (plz see the border-bottom).

Answer (score -2):

```
$('ul').function(){
$(this).css('padding-left','10px')

}
```